# Add new key-value pair at the beginning of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have list of dictionaries. Now, in every dictionary, **i want to add a key value pair(key : 'message1') at the beginning of the dict**, but when i add it , **its getting added to the end**.

Following is my code

```
data=[{
'message2': 'asd',
'message3': 'fgw',
'message4': 'fgeq',
'message5': 'gqe',
'message6': 'afgq',
'message7': 'major',
'message8': 'color-regular'
}]
for i in data:
    i['message1'] = '111'
```

Following is the output i am getting where message1 **is appended in the end**

```
[{'message2': 'asd',
'message3': 'fgw',
  'message4': 'fgeq',
  'message5': 'gqe',
  'message6': 'afgq',
  'message7': 'major',
  'message8': 'color-regular',
  'message1': '111'# i want this in the beginning}]
```

Please suggest a workaround

Answer (score 3):

On python3.7+ (cpython3.6+), dictionaries are ordered, so you can create a new dict with "message" as the first key:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = {'message': '111', **d}
```

```
data      
[{'message': '111',
  'message2': 'asd',
  'message3': 'fgw',
  'message4': 'fgeq',
  'message5': 'gqe',
  'message6': 'afgq',
  'message7': 'major',
  'message8': 'color-regular'}]
```

Comment: I tried the above snippet....I am getting error as "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict"
https://i.imgur.com/8PGUqr1.png

Comment: @Mahesh Whoops, just fixed a bug with the code, PTAL

Answer (score 2):

Simple way do to this can be create a dict first:

```
data = {'m1': 'A', 'm2': 'D'}
```

and then use update:

```
data.update({'m3': 'C', 'm4': 'B'})
```

Result will be `{'m1': 'A', 'm2': 'D', 'm3': 'C', 'm4': 'B'}`. The assumption is python version 3.7+ for an ordered dict. In the other way, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
dict1 = {
    '1': 'a',
    '2': 'b'
}

items = list(dict1.items())
items.insert(0, ('0', 'z'))
dict1 = dict(items)

print(dict1)
# {'0': 'z', '1': 'a', '2': 'b'}
```